# What parameters are estimated through the method of MLE?

Tags: maximum-likelihood

In the method of maximum likelihood estimation, we estimate a parameter(s) $\theta$ that will maximize some observed probability.

What usually is this $\theta$ parameter? Is it like a total count of a population(N), or mean ($\mu$) or standard deviation $\sigma$?

Comment: Probability is normally not observed. Can it be observed at all? In maximum likelihood estimation you are maximizing the joint probability density of the data as a function of the parameter(s) $\theta$ (rather than as a function of the observations, therefore it is called "likelihood" rather than probability density).

Comment: @RichardHardy, this is from [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Likelihood.html): "Likelihood is the hypothetical probability..." Also, in Baysian approach likelihood is closely linked to posterior probability

Comment: The point is that likelihood is not observed and it is not a probability.  In the Bayesian approach the likelihood multiplied by the prior is proportional to the posterior probability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be the population mean, or anything else, really. For instance, if you know the mean somehow, then you could estimate the variance of normal distribution from the data. In this case $\theta$ is your variance. However, you could fit both mean and variance to data, then your $\theta$ is a vector which consists of mean and variance as elements.

Answer (score 0):

Any quantity that governs the sampling distribution can be estimated using maximum likelihood.